# Pine Script Strategy doesn't work with volume

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=5
strategy("Volume Test Script", overlay=true)

conditionForBuy = volume > volume[1]*2
if(conditionForBuy)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
```

I am testing a strategy with pine script on tradingview, but the strategy never buys when the volume condition fulfills, but when I change this to a study, it's able to plot where the volume doubles from previous bar.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it buys alright. It just never sells as you don't have any piece of code for that. You are stuck in a long position.

[image]

Use `strategy.exit()` or `strategy.close()` to close your position.

Comment: no it doesn't buy alright, it never buys when the volume is double that of previous bar, try it

Comment: Well, it does buy. Can you show us an example with a screenshot where it does not buy?